Solve $1000(A-2D)-100B+10(C-2A)+D-2C=9$ without trial and error.
This is question $15$ from the Purple Comet math contest from the year $2005$.
The text of the question says:

And it came to pass that Jeb owned over a thousand chickens. So Jeb counted his
chickens. And Jeb reported the count to Hannah. And Hannah reported the count
to Joshua. And Joshua reported the count to Caleb. And Caleb reported the count
to Rachel. But as fate would have it, Jeb had over-counted his chickens by nine
chickens. Then Hannah interchanged the last two digits of the count before
reporting it to Joshua. And Joshua interchanged the first and the third digits of the
number reported to him before reporting it to Caleb. Then Caleb doubled the
number reported to him before reporting it to Rachel. Now it so happens that the
count reported to Rachel was the correct number of chickens that Jeb owned.
How many chickens was that?

Let $x$ represent the true number of chickens. Jeb reported $x+9$ to Hannah. I define $A,B,C,D$ as the digits of $x+9$, meaning $x+9=1000A+100B+10C+D$.
After the digit swaps by Hannah and Joshua, the number reported to Caleb is $1000D+100B+10A+C$. Caleb then doubles this number, and reports $2000D+200B+20A+2C$ to Rachel. Rachel was given the true value of $x$, so I can substitute into my equation above in place of $x$ and write the equation $(2000D+200B+20A+2C)+9=1000A+100B+10C+D$.
One equation with four variables, but of course I can also say that $A,B,C,D$ must be single-digit whole numbers with $A\neq0$.
I can gather like terms together and rewrite the equation as $980A+8C=1999D+100B+9$. I have a couple thoughts about this equation:

$D$ is likely a small value due to its large multiplier.
$D$ has to be odd, or the left and right sides of my equation would have opposite parity.

This was a quasi-dead end for me, as I can't see how else to manipulate the equation or put more restrictions on the variables to get to a solution without trial and error.
Indeed, I was able to get the right answer by trial and error using Desmos. Spoiler alert: if you open the link it shows the answer.
Some level of trial and error may have been intended by the writers of this contest. It is done in a team format, where teams can use any resources to answer $30$ questions over a period of $90$ minutes.
What I am asking for is this: is there a way to answer this question without any trial and error? Or can you at least put further restrictions on the variables to minimize trial and error? Thank you!

Following your thoughts, since $1999D \leq 1999D+100B+9 = 980A+8C \leq 980 \cdot 9 + 8 \cdot 9 = 8892$, then $1999D < 9995 = 5 \cdot 1999$. So $D=1$ or $D=3$.

Every transition except the last one leaves the remainder when dividing by $9$ unchanged.  If doubling also leaves that remainder unchanged, the original number must have been a multiple of $9$.

You can rewrite your last equation as:
$$
1000(A-2D)-100B+10(C-2A)+D-2C=9.
$$
It follows that $A-2D=0$, otherwise the first term on the left is too large. Plugging $A=2D$ into the equation one gets:
$$
C={39D+100B+9\over8}
$$
whose only solution is $D=1$ and $B=0$, otherwise the RHS would be too large, and consequently $C=6$ and $A=2$.

Saying that "$1000 (A - 2D)$ is too large" does require some proof, since we could have say $ A - 2D = 1, B = 9, C - 2A = -10, D - 2C = 9$.(As it turns out, this system doesn't have a solution in the positive integers.)

I believe you can close that gap using your approach, just applying $A-2D = 1$. $\quad$ Alternatively,  verify that with $ 0 \leq B \leq 9, -18 \leq C-2A \leq 8, -18 \leq D - 2C \leq 9 $, then we must have $ A - 2D \in {0, 1}$. And if $A-2D = 1$, we can quickly hunt down that ${ B, C-2A, D-2C } =$ ${9,  -10, 9 },  { 9, -9, -1}$, ${ 9,-8, -11}, { 8, -18, -11}$.  $\quad$ There's some case work still, but not as bad as OP's approach.

As you pointed, $D$ is odd. As pointed by @DavidMasi in the comments since $1999D=980A+8C-100B-9\le 980A+8C\le 980\cdot 9 + 8\cdot 9 = 8892$; $D\in\{1,3\}$. Further note $-18\le D-2C\le 9$. Thus taking your equation $\bmod{10}$ gives $D-2C\in \{-11,-1,9\}$.
Now suppose $D=3$. Then $C \in\{2,7\}$. Take the equation $\bmod{20}$ to give that $8C+D\equiv 9$. This case is thus rejected and $D=1$.
With $D=1$ we have $C\in\{1,6\}$. Then the equation becomes $245A+2C-25B=502$.
Taking $C=1$ gives that $245A-25B=500$ which gives further that $49A-5B=100$. Thus $A$ is a multiple of $5$; thus $A=5$. But that gives an invalid $B$. Thus $C=6$.
With $C=6$ the equation becomes $49A-5B=98$. Checking $\bmod 5$ we have $A\in\{2,7\}$. Putting $A=7$ gives $B=49$; contradiction. Thus $A=2$.
With $A=2$ we get that $B=0$. We get the solution $(A,B,C,D): (2,0,6,1)$. This gives the number of chicks as $\overline{\text{ABCD}} - 9 = \color{teal}{2052}$.
